# Can Stylus interpolate for a property value rather than a property name?

Tags: css, mixins, stylus

I'm trying to style `.tag` with a Mixin and Interpolation in Stylus. I would like the Mixin to take `tagName` as a variable and pass it down to the values of certain attributes in order to generate the variables for the values defined elsewhere.

Suppose I have a Stylus file that defines color variables for different `.tag`, like `color-TODO = red`. Then, to yield a CSS like:

```
.tag-TODO
  color: red                // from color-TODO
  background: blue          // from color-TODO-background
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px green // from color-TODO-shadow
```

, I would want to make another Stylus file with a Mixin like this:

```
tag(tagName)
  .tag-{tagName}                                // for .tag-TODO
    color: color-{tagName}                      // for color-TODO
    background: color-{tagName}-background      // for color-TODO-background
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px color-{tagName}-shadow  // for color-TODO-shadow

tag(TODO)                                       // to generate the selector with the properties
```

This doesn't work, presumably because `{}` after the property identifier gets interpreted literally rather than interpolated as a Mixin variable.

I wonder if there is a workaround. Is there a way (in Stylus) for a Mixin (or another construct) to generate different variable names sharing the same string as different property values?

Answer (score 0):

With the `convert()` built-in function (see https://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html), you can do this :

```
// your variables
color-TODO = #000
color-TODO-background = #666
color-TODO-shadow = #f2f2f2

// your mixin
tag(tagName)
  .tag-{tagName}
    color: convert("color-" + tagName)
    background: convert("color-" + tagName + "-background")      // for color-TODO- background
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px convert("color-" + tagName + "-shadow")  // for color-TODO-shadow

// execution
tag(TODO)
```

yields the css :

```
.tag-TODO {
  color: #000;
  background: #666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #f2f2f2;
}
```